# Upload file to server php api. need url of that file in response

Tags: php, android, api

I am developing a app in android in which file needs to store on server. i don't know much about php here is my php code that upload file to server perfectly but i want to it return file url .. what should i need to paste in echo part... i know something i have to put in echo .. but how ?

```
<?php
$file_path = "uploads/";
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line to your code,

```
 <?php
    $file_path = "uploads/";
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo json_encode(array("url","http://www.your_domain.com/".$file_path),"imageData");
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your welcome bro, rather than saying thanks to anyone try to express your feeling by upvote, downvote or by approving the answer. I not telling you because i want upvote but because it is an good habit to appriciate someone. Thanks.

Comment: yea but i need to wait 3 min for accepting answer . stack overflow showing me to wait 3 min to accept this answer.